# Get param from a parrallel namespace

Tags: ros, parameter, rosparam, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to figure out the best way to get param from a parallel namespace in my node code.

Here is my use case :

- I have a parameter b in namespace /a/
- A node launch in namespace /c/d/ where I try to access param b
- The namespace names and organisation can change and I do not know how

I try to use ros::param:search but it is only useful when you know the parameter namespace path

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264904/get-param-from-a-parrallel-namespace/) by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(*Assumption: you know the `parameter` names and they won't change.*)

I don't know if there's official API to achieve what you want. I've also browsed through [issues and pull requests on ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apulls+rospy+namespace+) but couldn't find anything relevant.

You can find the parameter full names that contains the parameter name (say "baa") in Python by something like:

```
lislis = [n for n in rospy.get_param_names() if n.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] == "baa"]

print(lislis)
['/namespace_foo/foobin/baa']
```

Note that this snippet is obviously not robust, as it is not searching the param name specifically.

---

UPDATE) I too wanted a way to search parameter names downward (i.e. "from left to right"). But AFAIK there's only upward search (e.g. [search_param](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Searching_for_parameter_keys)). My guess is that there can be multiple leaves of the parameter name (the right-most portion. E.g. "baa" in the example above) can exist (while the root of namespace must be unique) so that searching a leaf name can return multiple elements and thus won't be as useful (because it's hard to write a deterministic logic with multiple parameters returned?).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) on 2018-10-16**:
I do not test it yet but I think that it is the kind of trick that I was looking for.